# Owl Carousel Magento 2 whacky responsive behavior

Tags: jquery, css, magento

I had a css page running fine with OwlCarousel locally, but bringing it to Magento has introduced a slough of errors.

The one that's really got me is the way the page's responsiveness is behaving with Owl Carousel; at around 765px (my responsive stylesheet doesn't kick in until 640px), the entire page gets blasted off into giant dimensions.

Here's what Owl carousel looks like at a full-screen width.[image]

And here's what it looks like at 765px window width:

[image]

Anyone know what in Magento / OwlCarousel could cause these enormous numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The div section with a class of columns is set to display:flex on screen sizes 767px or below.
>
> ... setting of flex is better for smaller views, so to overcome this
>   issue, setting `overflow` to `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` on the
>   `div.column.main` has fixed the issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105638/owl-carousel-magento-2-not-fully-responsive

Oops, wound up finding an answer on Magento stack exchange.

Comment: how did you fix, still doesn't work for me, same issues mentioned in question?